# Loop onchange function to manipulate the target class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used php and jquery. I have to generate multiple select tag depends on the value of condition. I need to manipulate both html,php and and jquery  by using loop but I can't find the answer for this to work.

php html code... I like to populate multiple select tag with different classname

```
 <?php $count = 2; ?>
 <div id="comments" hidden><?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?></div>
 <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){ ?>
 

   <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="resone<?php echo $i; ?>" id="resone">
       <select name="artist_1" class="part<?php echo $i; ?>" id="part">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
        <option value="1">medicine</option>
        <option value="2">shoes</option>
       </select>
<?php }?>
```

jquery. I like to put the onchange function into the loop to manipulate the target class value

```
     <script>
           $(function() {
              var count = document.getElementById("comments").textContent;
                 for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {  
                $('.part' + i).change(function() {
                                            
                  var display = $('.part' + i).find(":selected").val();
                  $('.resone' + i).val(display);
    
                 })
           }
          
     })
</script>
```

I hope you could help me with this one.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Do not use ID in a loop. You should move the `<?php echo $i; ?>` to  `id="resone<?php echo $i; ?>"`

Comment: yeah but but target is the class in jquery

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but I would suggest to replace `resone` by `reason` since your form seems to be in english.

Comment: No need to add a number to the class. It is counterintuitive

Comment: i put them in the loop because the 2 generated select tag is not working. That is why I decided to manipulate the class

Comment: You could also add both classes, such as `class="reason reason-<?php echo $i; ?>"`. By convention, it is often a good practice to put hyphens between words in CSS classes or ids. For the name attribute, it's underscores as it is sent back to the server to be stored in variables.

Comment: but how do i  give an onchange funtion to the other select tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things and abusing the class by adding a counter to it.

Here is my suggestion - you can actually ignore the IDs and the script does not care about the count, just about how many ".part" there are

```js
$(function() {
  $(".part").on("change", function() {
    $(this).prev(".resone").val(this.value);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="resone" id="resone0">
<select name="artist_1" class="part" id="part0">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
  <option value="1">medicine</option>
  <option value="2">shoes</option>
</select>

<hr/>

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="resone" id="resone1">
<select name="artist_1" class="part" id="part1">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
  <option value="1">medicine</option>
  <option value="2">shoes</option>
</select>
```

PHP: - the IDs are not even used

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){ ?>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="resone" id="resone<?php echo $i; ?>">
   <select name="artist_1" class="part" id="part<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
    <option value="1">medicine</option>
    <option value="2">shoes</option>
   </select>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: the value of 2  count of select tag is just an example, my project is to apply discount to the order product. The number of select tag is defend on the number of  orderdered product.  that is why they are inside of a loop

Comment: @JuliusFernando this code is perfect for that case, as it works with an infinite number of `select` elements. This is the point being made; incremental id attributes add maintenance burden to the code which is unnecessary and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a for loop, just give the select a common class and do like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.part').change(function() {
    var display = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.resone').val(display);
  })
})
```

Since I can't see the element with the class `resone` i can't make sure if  `$(this).next('.resone').val(display)` works.

**Code example**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.part').change(function() {
    var display = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.resone').val(display);
  })
})
```

```html
<?php $count = 2; ?>
<div id="comments" hidden>
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?>
</div>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){ ?>

<select name="artist_1" class="part" >
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
  <option value="1">medicine</option>
  <option value="2">shoes</option>
</select>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Im so sorry , i just updated the code, there is aline to display the selected value.